# why isnt my work showing my transfer work

Tags: java

File Account.java contains a definition for a simple bank account class with methods to withdraw, deposit, get the balance and account number, and print a summary. Write the following additional code:

1. Add a method

   ```
   public void transfer(Account acct, double amount)
   ```

to the Account class that allows the user to transfer funds from one bank account to another. If acct1 and acct2 are Account objects, then the method call acct1.transfer(acct2,957.80) should transfer $957.80 from acct1 to acct2. Be sure to clearly document which way the transfer goes!

2. Write a class TransferTest with a main method that creates two bank account objects and enters a loop that does the following:

Asks if the user would like to transfer from account1 to account2, transfer from account2 to account1, or quit.
If a transfer is chosen, asks the amount of the transfer, carries out the operation, and prints the new balance for each account.
Repeats until the user asks to quit, then prints a summary for each account.

3. Add a static method to the Account class that lets the user transfer money between two accounts without going through either account. You can (and should) call the method transfer just like the other one – you are overloading this method. Your new method should take two Account objects and an amount and transfer the amount from the first account to the second account. The signature will look like this:

   ```
    public static void transfer(Account acct1, Account acct2, double amount)
   ```

Modify your TransferTest class to use the static transfer instead of the instance version.

```
public class Account {
    //instance variables
    private long accountNum; //bank account number
    private String name; //name
    private double balance; //balance
     
    
    //Constructor
    public Account () {
        accountNum = 0;
        name = "Nobody";
        balance = 0.0;
    }
     
    public Account (long accountNum, String name, double balance) {
        this.accountNum = accountNum;
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    
    //Accessor (get) methods
    public long getAccountNum() {
        return accountNum;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    //Mutator (set) methods
    public void setAccountNum (long newAccountNum) {
        this.accountNum = newAccountNum;
    }
    
    public void setName (String newName)
    {
        this.name = newName;
    }

    public void deposit (double amount) {
        if (amount >= 0) //enough money to withdraw 
         this.balance += amount;
    }

    public void withdraw (double amount) {
        if (amount >= 0 && balance >= amount)
         this.balance -= amount;
        
        else {
            System.out.println("Insufficient payment"); 
        }
        
    }
    
    public void transfer(Account acct, double amount) {
        //amount= 957.80; 

         if(this.balance >= amount) {
            acct.balance += amount; 
            this.balance-=amount; 
            System.out.println(amount + "successfully transfered from account1 to account 2" );
        }
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "Account Number: " + this.accountNum + "\nAccount Name: " + this.name + 
                "\nBalance: " + this.balance;
    }
    
    public boolean equals(Account otherAccount) {
        return this.accountNum == otherAccount.accountNum && 
                this.name.equalsIgnoreCase(otherAccount.name) &&
                (Math.abs(this.balance - otherAccount.balance) <= 0.001);
                
        
    }
    
    
    //Transfer from acct1 to acct2
    public static void transfer(Account acct1, Account acct2, double amount) {
        acct1.transfer(acct2, amount);
    }

    

    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    String confirm; 
    boolean done = false; 
    double amount1 = 0; 
    int choice; 
    
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to: " + "\n (1) Transfer money from account # "+acct1.getAccountNum()+
                " to account # " +acct2.getAccountNum()+ "\n (2) Transfer money from account # " +acct2.getAccountNum()+
                " to account # "+ acct1.getAccountNum()+ "\n (3) Quit");
        if(scan.hasNextInt()) {
            choice= scan.nextInt(); 
            scan.nextLine(); 
            if (choice==1|| choice ==2) {
                System.out.println("How much amount would you like to transfer? " ); 
                amount1=scan.nextDouble(); 
                scan.nextLine(); 
                }
            if(choice==1) {
                Account.transfer(acct1, acct2, amount1);
            }
            else if (choice==2) {
                acct2.transfer(acct1, amount1);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Quit \n Bye have a great day ");
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Please explain why this new code is different from the original code and why it works. Thank you.

Comment: Is it an answer to you own question or did you meant to ***add*** it to your question?

Comment: i just added it the first one is the account that was given and the second one is my work to print out

Comment: the first code is from the account and the second cod is from the transfer class